# Numpy histogram normalized with specified edges python

Tags: python, normalization, histogram

I am sure this topic came up before, but I cannot seem to find a real solution.

As you know, numpy.histogram is buggy when the edges are being specified imposing the condition

```
edges = array, where the array (or list) contains the coordinates of the edges.
```

On the documentation, it is suggested to use "Density" = True. However, on the numpy website, here is the condition for a proper normed histogram

```
 "Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen"
```

So, does anyone know how to produce the list

```
 values = histogram(list, bins = array (or list))
```

from a normalized distribution?

Thanks

Blaise

Answer (score 4):

It's not buggy, it does exactly what it should do ;)

As said in documentation for the `density` parameter:

> the result is the value of the probability density function at the bin, **normalized such that the integral over the range is 1**. Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen; **it is not a probability mass function**.

And as you can see in the example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, density=True)
>>> hist.sum()
2.4999999999999996
>>> np.sum(hist*np.diff(bin_edges))
1.0
```

So if you want the `density=True` and the sum over the hist to be equal to 1 you have to create bins of size 1. For the normal distribution you would do something like this:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(100)
>>> a.std(), a.mean(), a.max() - a.min()
(1.0468524976176077, -0.04129171877871838, 6.049084778833512)
>>> low, high = np.floor(a.min()), np.ceil(a.max())
>>> bins = np.linspace(low, high, high - low + 1)
>>> hist, edges = np.histogram(a, bins=bins, density=True)
>>> hist.sum()
1.0
```